# getting a plot of 3 competing species

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make a code for a model of competing three species to get plots ( polt 3d z against x,y and 2d plot x,y,z against time )
My model is

```
x'=(r1-a1x-b1y-c1z)x
y'=(r2-a2x-b2y-c2z)y
z'=(r3-a3x-b3y-c3z)z
```

where

```
r1=1.5; r2=2.65; r3=3.45;
a1=0.1; b1=0.3; c1=0.01; b2=0.2;
a2=0.3; c2=0.2; c3=0.2; a3=0.01; b3=0.1.
```

any help to do this code would be appreciated.

Comment: The Mathworks [has](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ordinary-differential-equations.html) excellent [examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html) and [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/summary-of-ode-options.html) on their ODE suite.  Please consult those and any related pages to make a first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem:

```
% Define diff. equations, time span and initial conditions, e.g.
tspan = [0 20];
y0 = [0.2 0.2 0.2];

r1=1.5;     r2=2.65;    r3=3.45;
a1=0.1;     a2=0.3;     a3=0.01; 
b1=0.3;     b2=0.2;     b3=0.1;
c1=0.01;    c2=0.2;     c3=0.2; 

dy = @(t,y) [
(r1-a1*y(1)-b1*y(2)-c1*y(3))*y(1);
(r2-a2*y(1)-b2*y(2)-c2*y(3))*y(2);
(r3-a3*y(1)-b3*y(2)-c3*y(3))*y(3)];

% Solve differential equations
[t,y] = ode45(dy, tspan, y0);
```

Now just plot the results:

```
% Plot all species against time
figure(1)
plot(t,y)

% 3D plot of z against xy
figure(2)
plot3(y(:,1), y(:,2), y(:,3))
grid on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping .. in the plot of z against x,and y , could you please tell me how to do it spiral in

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to manipulate the data, such that it spirals in? Or do you want this exact data to be plotted in such a way that it spirals in? The former would imply that you corrupt you data, and the latter would be difficult as the plot now represents your actual data. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Also, if the answer itself was correct, please accept it (click the checkbox) and upvote. I woudl truly appreciate it :P

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the data, such that it spirals in? yes please, and I have found the equilibrium points (8 equli. points) so the eighth equilibrium is stable and the behavior of the solution is spiral in based on the eigenvalue `( -3.4576,  -0.0840 - 1.3723i,  -0.0840 + 1.3723i)`, so how to show that it is spiral in

Comment: Hmm, could you post your entire problem? I suppose this is related to optimization and/or control theory, correct?

Comment: It is related to dynamical system (mathematical biology) my problem is this model, so i need to find the behavior of the solution numerically like in the link . see this example it is almost the same model , but the only  difference is in the plus sign in the second equation .[link](http://www.veltechuniv.edu.in/ijmsc/current_issue/IJMSC02-01-Final-Paper-12.pdf)